# mydomain[dot]com without WWW doesn't load website

Tags: nginx

when I got to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) it working properly. But when I go to mydomain.com without the ''www'' it not working it give me this error :

```
We can’t connect to the server at mydomain.com. Did you mean to go to www.mydomain.com?
```

How can I fix that ? Here is my nginx config file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/mydomain;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/mydomain;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/mydomain.sock;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- please verify that the DNS A/AAAA records are the same , being able to connect only to one of these indicates such a problem
- have you checked the address bar of you browser for `https://` since firefox and maybe other browser try https:// if they cannot reach http://